# WPF modal window behaves weird

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

I 'm running into a situation i don't understand and want somebody to enlighten me if possible.

Created a WPF application. For sake of simplicity consider this application to be one window. I put some controls on this window, amongst others there is a TextBox control (let's call it TB).

There is a requirement that this TB must always have the focus (in case someone types something or something is read through the barcode-scanner it should appear there).

I thought implementing this with the help of a timer: every second the focus is transferred to the TB.

Until now everything works fine (as expected).

The weird thing is the following: let's say a new user wants to use this window, so she has to sign in. I thought implementing this with a new Window object (let's call it W2), calling it this way:

```
W2.ShowDialog();
```

This W2 window should be modal (bear in mind that the timer still executes).

The crazy thing is that under *Windows Vista* this works **perfectly** as expected (this means W2 is modal and the user can to what she should do on W2), **BUT** on Windows XP as soon as the user wants to type something in a textbox of W2 the focus is set back to TB on the initial Window (as far as i can interpret: this means W2 is **not** modal!!!? am i right?).

How can i overcome this situation?

Is this the right approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to set the [Owner property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) of W2 to your main Window.

From the referenced docs:

> When you open a child window by calling ShowDialog, you should also set the Owner property of the child window.

Comment: To be honest: i didn't set this. I think you 're right! This must be the missing part. But on the other side: why is it working on Windows Vista?

Comment: @Sawas: For some reason, this doesn't seem to behave exactly the same in XP - in Vista/7, not setting this doesn't usually cause problems (though, technically, it should be set there, too)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this setting-the-focus-back-every-few-seconds is such a good idea. It is always possible that some input will come in the interval between a lost and got focus state (and be lost). Alternative solutions are catching the PreviewKeydown event on the form that the TB resides on and somehow set the output of a barscanner to the TB too.

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me into this direction. I have to dig around to see how to implement using this technique. +1 from me! Thanks again very much